# Rails Multiple Table Inheritance: Get parent errors from child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

I'm using active_record-acts_as gem to implement multiple table inheritance. My scenario:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   actable
   before_destroy :some_validations

   def some_validations
      if some_condition
         errors.add(:base, "cant be deleted")
         return false
      else
         return true
      endif
   end

end

class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end

class Train < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end
```

If I execute:

```
p = Plane.first
p.destroy
```

It returns `false` as expected, however, upon executing:

`p.errors.messages` I get:

```
{}
```

How can I get parent's errors upong calling child.errors?